# Can a small aquarium breed fish?

Tags: subnautica

There are a lot of resources in breeding fish in a large aquarium (now called an Alien Containment Tank) that fits inside a multipurpose room, but there is very little information I could find about the smaller aquarium (just called Aquarium).

Basically, I built one in my Cyclops and wanted to stock it with bladderfish so I could easily farm water while away from my base. I put two in there, and I know it takes time, but it's been several day/night cycles and there are still only two. Does anyone know if they will actually breed, or do I just need to fill them up with 8 fish (max # of slots) and perhaps just make multiple tanks for storage.

I already have a growbed on the sub, with Chinese potato plants (15health/3thirst), so looking to extend the duration of my voyages without having to make a bunch of cured fish, which doesn't help the water situation, and can't put a filtration system on the Cyclops.

Update:

It's been about 10-12 day/night cycles, and still only 2 bladderfish, starting to lose hope...

[image: Cyclops Aquarium]

Comment: Not a direct answer but... Lantern Fruit. It's only 5 HP and 3 Water, but dozens grow on a single plant and they regrow so quickly, it's almost ludicrous. I have 6 of these in pots and they're easily capable of feeding me and also make my water needs less severe. I'm thinking of reducing to three to save space. Only downside... Fruit rots _fast_ so great at cyclops, less good when out and about.Salted reginalds can be used if you want an extended voyage. Also, get a lot of purifiers running at the base and stock up a couple of large cabinets with water.Not  quite 100% self-sufficient but close

Comment: Without doubt, a single indoor grow bed with 16 marble melons will completely satisfy both hunger and thirst. When you get the warning for thirst, harvest 6 melons and eat them. this will fill your water to max. then cut 2 more melons to make 8 seeds and plant those.  By the time you get the warning again all will be fully grown.  If you are going out on an extended harvesting run inthe PRAWN, take one +50 bottle and one salted reginald - they are all you will need even on a longish journey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Small Aquarium doesn't breed fish at all. For cyclops voyages, you are going to want those chinese potatoes you have, and a couple of slots with Bulbo Trees. Use a knife on them to harvest, and they give 3Hunger/10Thirst. IMO, more beneficial to have than any other plant, as thirst seems to drain faster than hunger. Also, you may even want to swap those potatoes for Marblemelons that give 22/15, if I remember correctly. Cut one and it turns into 4 seeds, which take up 1 slot each, unlike most other crops, and when each of those turn into a full-size Marblemelon, harvest 3, and your hunger and thirst will fill rapidly.

Answer (score 4):

These are only decorative. The large aquarium was added specifically to provide the breeding feature, so there is also little chance that the decorative aquarium will ever be updated to allow breeding.

Answer (score 0):

The main question has already been addressed by the other answers: No, the aquarium cannot breed fish.

But regarding the underlying problem of having sufficient water for your journey, you might want to consider adding some walllockers to your cyclops (if i recall correctly some are already installed). You can fill those up with large water bottles (+50 water) from your water filtration machine.

That might be more efficient than bladder fish. Which are a hassle to gather.

Comment: I had tons of lockers -- the point was to be complete self sufficient -- ie if I used up all my stored resources. Not that it ever happened, but it's what I was thinking at the time.